# react-native run-android not connected to logs, sending old version

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I changed my `targetSDKVersion` from 27 to 28 and now when I run `react-native run-android` my app builds, the react-native server starts but I then see `Starting: Intent { cmp=com.appname/.MainActivity }` and not the logs from the application. The application is also not updated to reflect changes.

Things I've tried so far:

- Change targetSdkVersion back to 27
- Clean & Build via Android Studio
- Gradlew clean

Short of starting a new project and migrating everything over, is there something else I can try?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to resolve the issue in the existing project, but creating a new react-native project `react-native init projectname` and copying the src over worked.